# knockout binding for simple object not working

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I can make knockout work for array or simple object but not for a simple json object.
Can someone provide pointers plz.

http://jsfiddle.net/aECM9/

html:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>customer Number: </td><td data-bind="text: customerData().reference"></td></tr>
        <tr><td>customer Name: </td><td data-bind="text: customerData().name"></td></tr>
        <tr><td>customer Manager Code: </td><td data-bind="text: customerData().managerCode"></td></tr>
    </tbody>        
</table>
```

javascript:

```
        var viewModel = {
            customerData: ko.observable()
        };

        ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

        viewModel.customerData({
            reference: 123,
            name: "bob",
            managerCode: 321
        });
```

Answer (score 4):

Look at the console. When you call `applyBindings` it throws an error because it tries to access `customerData().reference` but `customerData()` is undefined at this point. Move your `.applyBindings` below where you assign the `customerData` value.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/aECM9/2/

Another alternative would be to use an `if` binding to stop knockout from trying to bind properties on `customerData()` before it has a value:

```
 <tbody data-bind="if: customerData()">
```

Now nothing after this to the closing `</tbody>` tag will be rendered if `customerData()` is falsy.

http://jsfiddle.net/aECM9/3/

I used `tbody`, but you could use any appropriate parent tag or even a virtual tag:

```
<!-- ko if: customerData() -->
```